# Seat Mii: intermittent, now permanent electric power steering fault

Tags: troubleshooting, power-steering, steering, electronics, seat

One year ago I bought a used Seat Mii. From time to time I had problems with the (electromechanical, not hydraulic) power steering: it would stop working and its red light would come up. Turning off and on again the engine always solved the problem. Sometimes with the power steering red light on, the yellow traction control light would turn on as well, even though I wasn't losing traction or driving really slowly in my town. This made me think of some fault sensor readings.

One week ago the power steering had this problem once again, but from that day the problems looks permanent, shutting everything down doesn't help.

I looked up online but didn't find anything useful, only reports of similar problems. I have the impression that this always happened after driving in the awful roads of my town, maybe causing some electrical connectors to lose contact.
I checked all the fuses and they're not broken. I'd like to check the power steering electrical board, but it's located under the steering wheel, is there a way to remove the big plastic cover over it? I'd like to know possible causes for this problem, and how they can be fixed, thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!